# Is Float, Double, Int an AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I read inline documentation of Swift and I am bit confused.

1) `Any` is a protocol that all types implicitly conform.

2) `AnyObject` is a protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.

3) `Int`, `Float`, `Double` are structs

Here is a sample code:

```
import UIKit

func passAnyObject(param: AnyObject) {
    print(param)
}

class MyClass {}
struct MyStruct {}

let a: Int = 1
let b = 2.0
let c = NSObject()
let d = MyClass()
let e = MyStruct()

passAnyObject(a)
passAnyObject(b)
passAnyObject(c)
passAnyObject(d)
//passAnyObject(e) // Argument type 'MyStruct' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'


if a is AnyObject { // b, d, e is also AnyObject
    print("\(a.dynamicType) is AnyObject")
}
```

What I don't understand is why `Int`, `Double`, `Float` are `AnyObject`s? Why compiler doesn't say anything? Those types are declared as structs. Struct `MyStruct` cannot be passed to the method on the top because it does not conform to `AnyObject`.

Could you help me understand why `Int`, `Double` and `Float` are `AnyObject` or why compiler thinks they are?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because you have Foundation imported, `Int`, `Double`, and `Float` get converted to `NSNumber` when passed to a function taking an `AnyObject`.  Type `String` gets converted to `NSString`.  This is done to make life easier when calling *Cocoa* and *Cocoa Touch* based interfaces.  If you remove `import UIKit` (or `import Cocoa` for OS X), you will see:

```
error: argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'
```

when you call

```
passAnyObject(a)
```

This implicit conversion of value types to objects is described [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

---

#### Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6):

Passing an `Int`, `Double`, `String`, or `Bool` to a parameter of type `AnyObject` now results in an error such as **Argument of type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'AnyObject'**.

With Swift 3, implicit type conversion has been removed.  It is now necessary to cast `Int`, `Double`, `String` and `Bool`  with `as AnyObject` in order to pass it to a parameter of type `AnyObject`:

```
let a = 1
passAnyObject(a as AnyObject)
```

Comment: You're right. Removed `import UIKit` and they does not conform now. Thanks!

Comment: @vacawama: can you explain what "converted" means here specifically ?

Comment: @robo, the compiler creates an `NSNumber` object for you in this case.  If for instance you pass an `Int` to `func test(val: AnyObject)` and then test that inside of your function with `if val is NSNumber { print("true") }` it will indeed print `true` because the `Int` becomes an `NSNumber`.

Comment: This no longer seems to be true in Swift 3 in Xcode beta 6. Could someone let me know what proposal got this feature/bug implemented?

Comment: @shrutim, SE-0072 seems to be the culprit. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md  Note: Any Swift value can also be converted to its boxed id representation with `as AnyObject`.

Comment: Check out my answer, why the compiler is not giving any error in my case? I have not imported any framework.

Answer (score 1):

Good find! `UIKit` actually converts them to `NSNumber` - also mentioned by @vacawama. The reason for this is, sometimes you're working with code that returns or uses `AnyObject`, this object could then be cast (`as!`) as an `Int` or other "structs".

Comment: Just a note that forced cast is not recommended.

Comment: Check out my answer, why the compiler is not giving any error in my case? I have not imported any framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {

static func test() {
    let anyObjectsValues: [AnyObject] = [1, "Two", 3, "Four"] as [AnyObject]
    anyObjectsValues.forEach { (value) in
        switch value {
        case is Int:
            print("\(value) is an Int!")
        case is String:
            print("\(value) is a String!")
        default:
            print("\(value) is some other type!")
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have not imported UIKit or Foundation frameworks. Why compiler is not giving any error? Even it printing the result.

Output:

1 is an Int!

Two is a String!

3 is an Int!

Four is a String!

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: If you add `print(type(of: value))` after the end of the `switch` you will see that the underlying types are still `NSString` and `NSNumber` based.  Swift must now include parts of `Foundation` even if you don't import it explicitly.  BTW, your "answer" isn't really an answer and should be deleted and posted as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted it here just because to maintain the same thread about the doubt of AnyObject. So that other developers can also be clear.