# Type Casting For AnyObject to represent instances of any reference type

Tags: swift, anyobject

```
 var array = [AnyObject]()
 struct Test {}
 array.append(Test())
```

When I write this code in the play ground it gives me the following error **Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'**

I am guessing it is failing because struct is a value type not a reference type. 
But when I run this code

```
var array = [AnyObject]()
array.append(1)
array.append(2.0)
array.append("3")
```

It works
but these are all also value types but in this case no error is given **Why?**

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554435/5475238

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your success case, there is some conversion going on behind the scenes.

Try adding this at the end of your appends to see what's happening:

```
for item in array {
    print(item.dynamicType)
}
```

Comment: It is printing this __NSCFNumber
__NSCFNumber
_NSContiguousString but my value types were number, double and string

Comment: This "some conversion" is documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html: String -> NSString; Int, Float, Double -> NSNumber.

Comment: @MartinR  I was going with the "seeing is believing" theory.  :)

Comment: So you both mean the conversion goes like this number types to NSNumber
strings to NSString
arrays to NSArray
dictionaries to NSDictionary?